# Partition existing table using interval partitioning in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, partitioning

I want to partition an existing table in oracle 12 using interval partition and list subpartitions.
I have found some information on how to partition subsequently in range, but not using interval partition.
I want to tell the database the first partition and which value (date) it has and he will auto-create the rest for all datasets in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE MODIFY
 PARTITION BY RANGE(TESTDATE) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
 SUBPARTITION BY LIST(COMPANY_NR) (
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01.01.2018 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
 (
    SUBPARTITION P_1 VALUES(1),
    SUBPARTITION P_2 VALUES(2)
  )
 );
```

Is the auto creation of the partitions with interval possible that way? I cannot find any info anywhere. And if yes, what am I doing wrong here? It says I am missing subpartition keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (...)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (TESTDATE) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
    SUBPARTITION BY LIST (COMPANY_NR)
    SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE 
    (
        SUBPARTITION P_1 VALUES (1),
        SUBPARTITION P_2 VALUES (2)
        SUBPARTITION P_others VALUES (DEFAULT)
    )
    (
        PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2018-01-01')
    );
```

You can change subpartition template on existing table, see [Modifying a Subpartition Template](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-48168ACC-BA2A-4D2B-B693-F01DDAD82682.htm#VLDBG1192)

However, if you like to change partition then you have to use the [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042) package.